# How to automate conversion of all my Google docs to PDF or office?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, download, bulk-download

The other day I decided to back up my entire Google Drive to my encrypted external hard drive. After one day downloading I managed to do it (including the pictures). Anyway, I should have known better: all Google docs are, obviously just links to the Google docs URL

They are many, so converting them manually one by one is not an option. Can anyone think of a way to automate this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are links, however, if you go to your Drive and select **Download**, then all Google docs files get converted to MS doc files and downloaded to your hard drive as standalone files, not as reference links:

[image: 0]

### _______________________________________________________________

as an alternative, you can try to get an add-on of your choice by typing: **`pdf conv`**

[image: 0]

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to [takeout.google.com](https://takeout.google.com/)
2. Deselect all and select only Drive.

By default, the data will be downloaded in MS format, but if you want your data in different formats (e.g. PDF), click on "Multiple formats" before going to the next step.